# Presenting VC embedded in a NavController from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to want to present/push a VC embedded in a NavController from AppDelegate. I previously used this code but somehow it's not working anymore:

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let VC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PendingRequest") as! PendingRequestVC
    let navController = UINavigationController.self(rootViewController: VC)

    let rootViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.rootViewController
    rootViewController!.presentViewController(navController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Other codes open my desired VC but not within a navigation pane. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Calling from AppDelegate after user interacts with push notification.

Edit:
I'm able to present the right VC by using this code:

```
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    if let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PendingNavController") as? UINavigationController {
        if let yourViewController = viewController.topViewController as? PendingRequestVC {
            //yourViewController.getRequestdata()
        }
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.rootViewController = viewController;
    }
```

But this code won't allow me to go back using the Close button on my NavBar.
My structure is as follow:

TabController -> NavController1 -> VC1 -> NavController1a -> VC1a
I'm trying to get to VC1a and be able to use the Closed button to go back to VC1

Comment: Why do you want to do this through the app Delegate?

Comment: Is it embedded in navigation controller on storyboard?

Comment: @lukesIvi I should've mention it: action after user interacts with push notification.

Comment: @ShehzadAli yes it's within a Navigation Controller

Comment: So if you look at storyboard, Does it showing an arrow behind your Navigation controller? Which actually means navigation controller is your root view controller or your rootViewController is some other View controller?

Comment: @ShehzadAli it doesn't show the small, it's not my root.

Comment: Update your question.

Comment: Why are you doing this in `appDelegate`? Is there any Condition like application is coming from background or By Default you want to show present this in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `appDelegate` even if application is running for the first time

Comment: @ShehzadAli app is in the background, user receives a push notification and when he clicks/swipes the notif I want to bring him to the VC that will display further info.

Comment: Your code looks fine and I have also tried this its working. Have you tried this in `func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication)`? What errors you are getting after the execution of this code?

Comment: @ShehzadAli I was putting the code in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` and it's giving me the warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController> on <UINavigationController> whose view is not in the window hierarchy. Tried from `DidBecomeActive` but it activates it when I first launch app.

Comment: Try the code mentioned below:

Comment: @ShehzadAl tried the code and doesn't present the VC (but no crash). I'm able to present VC with a different code (see edit) but I cannot go back using the close button on my nav controller.

Comment: its default back button isn't taking you back?

Comment: No button does nothing

Comment: I have updated my answer for you check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a UIButton in your presented ViewController's View. Following event will be performed by that button. You can dismiss your Navigation Controller this way

```
@IBAction func dismissViewController(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.navigationController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion:nil);

}
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your patience, got it to work with your code and some tweaking here and there!